# SOME DATES ARE NOT SHOWED IN CHROME

Tags: date, extjs, grid

i'am using Extjs 4.2. I had implemented an app using grids, but i'am having an issue just only in crhome. Some Dates are not showed in the grid. This is the part of my view:

```
{
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraLlegadaOrigen',
                                text: 'FechaHoraLlegadaOrigen',
                                format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraDespachoOrigen',
                                text: 'FechaHoraDespachoOrigen',
                                format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraLlegadaTumbes',
                                text: 'FechaHoraLlegadaTumbes',
                                format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s'
                                }
                            }...
```

And when i check chrome with its dev tools, i got the following incoming data to fill the grid:

{"listafichatransporte":[{"Id":"1","IdEmpresa":"12","Empresa":"DYS NEVADOS ","Contacto":"Violeta Olivera","Celular":"943200859","Placa1":"A7Z -847","Capacidad":"24 ","Chofer":"Moises Quispe  Fernandez","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"985314508","CelularEcuador":"987049690","Termoregistro1":"b","Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"05/02/2013 10:30:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"05/02/2013 00:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"05/03/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"2","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"QUITO","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"1","IdChofer":"1","IdCamionChofer":"10","Grower":"COMPOSITAN / JUREM"},{"Id":"2","IdEmpresa":"13","Empresa":"ECUACARGAS","Contacto":"GUSTAVO TORRES","Celular":"993418166","Placa1":"PAA-4803","Capacidad":"20 SKIDS","Chofer":"VICTOR HUGO FEIJOO","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"0051-957576513","CelularEcuador":"997511731","Termoregistro1":null,"Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"05/05/2013 00:00:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"05/05/2013 00:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"05/06/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"2","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"QUITO","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"2","IdChofer":"2","IdCamionChofer":"18","Grower":"COMPOSITAN / JUREM"},{"Id":"3","IdEmpresa":"13","Empresa":"ECUACARGAS","Contacto":"GUSTAVO TORRES","Celular":"993418166","Placa1":"PAB-2090","Capacidad":"20 SKIDS","Chofer":"WILLIAM NARVAEZ","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"0051- 950659189","CelularEcuador":"995379357","Termoregistro1":null,"Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"05/07/2013 00:00:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"05/07/2013 00:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"05/08/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"3","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"GUAYAQUIL","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"3","IdChofer":"3","IdCamionChofer":"19","Grower":"COMPOSITAN / JUREM"},{"Id":"4","IdEmpresa":"13","Empresa":"ECUACARGAS","Contacto":"GUSTAVO TORRES","Celular":"993418166","Placa1":"PZQ-807","Capacidad":"20 SKIDS","Chofer":"JIMMY OBANDO","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"0051-963-995-83","CelularEcuador":"0991-515-348","Termoregistro1":null,"Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"30/06/2013 13:00:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"30/06/2013 22:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"01/07/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"2","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"QUITO","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"4","IdChofer":"4","IdCamionChofer":"20","Grower":"COMPOSITAN"},{"Id":"5","IdEmpresa":"13","Empresa":"ECUACARGAS","Contacto":"GUSTAVO TORRES","Celular":"993418166","Placa1":"OAA-1457","Capacidad":"20 SKIDS","Chofer":"EUCEBIO GOMEZ","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"0051-971-691-62","CelularEcuador":"0985-985-783","Termoregistro1":"CORINOR 425971 PHR 373","Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"30/06/2013 00:00:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"30/06/2013 19:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"01/07/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"2","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"QUITO","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"5","IdChofer":"5","IdCamionChofer":"21","Grower":"CORINOR / AGROCASPI"},{"Id":"6","IdEmpresa":"12","Empresa":"DYS NEVADOS ","Contacto":"Violeta Olivera","Celular":"943200859","Placa1":"A7Z -847","Capacidad":"24","Chofer":"GERMAN TRONCOSO","Nextel":"999999999","CelularPeru":"943200861","CelularEcuador":"No informaron","Termoregistro1":"COMPOSITAN 425982 PHR 483","Termoregistro2":null,"IdPuntoRecojo":"1","PuntoRecojo":"TRUJILLO","FHTranspPuntoRecojo":"01/07/2013 09:00:00","FHDespaPuntoRecojo":"01/07/2013 00:00:00","FHLlegadaTumbes":"02/07/2013 00:00:00","IdPuntoLlegada":"2","PuntoLlegadaEcuador":"QUITO","FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador":" ","IdCamion":"1","IdChofer":"6","IdCamionChofer":"15","Grower":"CORINOR / COMPOSITAN"}]}

So, the rows 4 and 5 don't show date fields FHDespaPuntoRecojo, and FHLlegadaTumbes, but in firefox and i.e. they are showed. Besides the other rows the data is showed normally.

So, what can i do to fix this on chrome. Any idea?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using a local store to fill the grid. Make sure that the date-fields are correctly configured in your store, like so:

```
fields: [
    'someField',
    'someOtherField,
    {
        name: 'someDateField',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: No, i am using a ajax call to get data. I understand you wanted to say my model field date type must be well defined... This is my model definition:         

{
            name: 'FechaHoraLlegadaOrigen',
            type: 'date'
        },
        {
            name: 'FechaHoraDespachoOrigen',
            type: 'date'
        },
        {
            name: 'FechaHoraLlegadaTumbes',
            type: 'date'
        }.

I think is ok, any other idea...? Or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Not at the moment. Please vote up so I get a few points. I need to get to 50.

Comment: You should definitely not accept an answer as accepted if it does not satisfy your problem. You won't get any more answers.  If that's the case, click on the green check-mark to un-accept it.